# Linear Algebra: abstract/general vector space (Determinant space) Dimension theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have this linear algebra question

Note the transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
\begin{equation}
T(x_1,x_2) = \det\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ -5 & 5 \end{bmatrix}\\
\end{equation}

So for this transformation we need to find the kernel and verify the Rank-Nullity Theorem.

So far, I can choose values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ to get the determinant to be zero.
So from determinant we would get:

$x_1\cdot5 - (-5)\cdot x_2 = 0$

$5x_1+5x_2 = 0$

And cleaning this up, we get:
$x_1 = -x_2$

So the vectors in the kernel form this vector:
$$
(x_1,x_2) = (x_1,-x_1) = x_1(1,-1)
$$
So we have this parameterized solution using $x_1$ as a parameter.
So this I believe is 1-dimensional. So Nullity = 1.

But how to get the rank and with the dimension of the domain, not too sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Everything you have done is fine, now use the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)

Comment: OK, my question is, since the domain space of T is $R^2$, does that mean that dim(V) = 2.

Comment: So from the equation  of rank-nullity theorem we would have: Rank(T) + Nullity(T) = dim(V), hence Rank(T) = dim(V) - Nullity(T) = 2 -1 = 1?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it.

Comment: Ok, so based on the definition of T:V->W, I guess that we always are given the dimensions of V and W in general then?

Comment: The dimension of $W$ is actually not used in the theorem. But yes, the dimension of $V$ is relevant and needed

Comment: OK, that is one part of the puzzle i needed to know then, that was kind of holding me back. Thanks again 'b00n heT', really appreciate your input. I will give you as the correct answer to this question.

Comment: you are welcome Palu!